# How to hide tabbed panel in JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing

I have:

```
JTabbedPane jtabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
jTabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", panel1);
jTabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", panel2);
jTabbedPane.addTab("Tab 3", panel3);
```

What I want to do is hide Tab 2 when a condition occurs (say the user isn't permitted to access that tabbed panel.

Yes I know you can do:

```
jtabbedPane.setEnabled(1, false); // disable Tab 2
```

which will gray it out, ***but I want to completely hide it so that the user doesn't even know it's even a possibility in the software***. They shouldn't be even aware that it exists.

I do NOT want to do

```
jtabbedPane.remove(1); // remove Tab 2
```

because I then have to remove/add on a regular basis.

Comment: *"I want to completely remove"* but *"I do NOT want to do (use) `jtabbedPane.remove`"*.  I think you've got yourself into a catch 22 position.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I meant to say hide. I've edited the question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to avoid adding the tab in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way is to remove it when you don't want to see it, and re-add it later when you do want it visible.

Answer (score 2):

This work in my project.

```
this.TabbedPane.setEnabledAt(1, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done only by custom component.

Here is an api for [HideableTabbedPane](http://www-mipl.jpl.nasa.gov/vicar/vicar350/html/javadoc/jpl/mipl/mars/viewer/util/HideableTabbedPane.html) try that

Comment: Where is the source or jar? It's not part of the standard JDK

Comment: It's a private developer, not a standard class.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:-** why don't you just start x at the value of 1, so it skips 0, instead of starting at 0 and checking for x>1...

**Solution 2:-**  [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html#tabapi][1]

[1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html#tabapi use that link.

**Solution 3:**- You can do something like this, which just doesn't paint the tabArea

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
class Testing { 
public void buildGUI() { 
JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane(); 
tp.addTab("A",getPanel("A")); 
tp.addTab("B",getPanel("B")); 
tp.addTab("C",getPanel("C")); 
tp.setUI(new javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalTabbedPaneUI(){ 
protected void paintTabArea(Graphics g,int tabPlacement,int selectedIndex){} }); 
JFrame f = new JFrame(); 
f.getContentPane().add(tp); 
f.pack(); 
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
f.setVisible(true);
 } 
public JPanel getPanel(String tabText)
 { 
JPanel p = ...
```

Comment: The problem is that if you're overriding the paintTabArea you're assuming you know the L&F UI manager (you're using the default Java L&F UI managers which I'm not - they don't look so good). However if you have custom ones, or different ones depending on the OS, this code can quickly become pretty complex and unmaintainable. If the L&F is ever changed, that will be one difficult nugget to find. It is possible, but if I had to choose between removing tabs and re-adding them versus this, I would just do the first.